# CSS :not workaround for Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

The [following example](http://jsfiddle.net/BZeLR/) works in Firefox 4, but not in Internet Explorer 8:

HTML:

```
<div class='first'>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
```

CSS:

```
div:not(.first) {
    color: red;
}
```

What workaround would you suggest to make it work in both browsers ?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but in the above code you could use the `:first-child` selector rather than `class='first'`

Comment: [IE9.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) appears to implement this selector in IE...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why can't you do this?:

```
div {
    color: red;
}
div.first {
    color: inherit;/* or whatever color you want*/
}
```

It isn't really a `:not()` workaround, but it works for your example as far as I can tell. If you didn't have the class you could always use `:first-child` as well.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Madmartigan/BZeLR/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Not perfect but works:

```
div {
   color: red;
}

div.first {
   //some other colour
}
```

EDIT: Or what madmartigan said